# code involving fading, time and sound

Tags: image, audio, timer, processing, fade

I am a student learning to become a comic artist.
Now we have this course called "Media" in wich we have to make an interactive program using a program called processing.

I have to show this to a jury in 2 days but I am litteraly stuck with these codes for the past 3 weeks, I just can't get it to work the way I want it to, so here I ask you if anyone would be able to help me with this.

What I want to make :

Basically I wanted it to be interactive without being interactive, So I tried to accomplish this by making a Buddha-themed program.
So what does it have to do? I think it shouldn't be all that hard, all I want it to do is take the amount of sound it gets, and when the sound is below a certain amount, the screen, wich is completely white, will start fading to black, whenever there is sound it will rapidly become white again.
So after 30 seconds of no sound it should be completely black and it should go into a new mechanism where it will start fading the black screen ( there is a picture with the word "emptyness" behind it ) so that word should start becoming visible very slowly ( approx 30 seconds again ) then when that picture is completely visible it should start fading again and start showing a picture of a buddha ( wich is behind that picture with the word ) and that's all I want it to do.

So now I will show you what I have, I've got the screen fading whenever it's really quite, but that's where I get stuck, I don't know how to set the timer, how to set the images behind it etc :

```
import ddf.minim.*;

Minim minim;
AudioInput in;

PImage img;
int a = 125;//sound value
int fade = 0;//starting fade, big fade is darker
int stmin = 2; //fadestep darker
int stplus = 20; //fadestep lighter
float gw = 0.001;//sensitivity smaller = more sensitive

void setup() {
   img = loadImage("emptyness.jpg");
background(0);
size(1000, 1000);
frameRate(10); // Maximum 30 frames/images per second

minim = new Minim(this); 
// get a line in from Minim, default bit depth is 16
in = minim.getLineIn(Minim.STEREO, 640);
}

void draw() {

image(img, 10,10);
fill(255);
rect(0,0,1000,1000);

if (abs(in.left.get(a))> (gw)) {
fade = fade-stplus;
}
else {
fade = fade+stmin;
}
fade = constrain(fade,0,300);
fill(0,fade);
rect(0,0,1000,1000);
}

void stop()
{
// always close Minim audio classes when you are done with them
in.close();
minim.stop();

super.stop();
}
```

I really hope someone can help me with this for posting this here really is my last resort, I have only 2 days left untill my jury, i've been trying, getting crashes, and the worst thing of all, I really don't understand anything about java or processing cause we never got any lessons about it, they just expected us to 'find out ourselves'

thanks for reading this, and hopefully someone can help me

greetz and lots of thanks in advance

Comment: Crossposted: http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/2696/need-help-with-a-code-minim-fading#Item_2

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

The advice I gave you on the Processing forum still stands: You have to break your problem down into smaller individual steps and take on those steps one at a time instead of trying to tackle the whole thing at once.

Can you create a simple sketch that just fades to black after 30 seconds?

Can you create a simple sketch that fades to black after 30 seconds, but then fades back to white when you click the mouse?

Can you create a simple sketch that shows you whether it can hear sound?

Now can you combine those ideas to create a sketch that fades to black after 30 seconds, but fades back to white when it hears a sound?

This might seem like a lot for 2 days (and that's a lesson in time management), but you'll have better luck if you take a step back and focus on one small thing at a time instead of your whole project. That will also allow you to ask more specific questions, as this one is too broad to really answer without doing your homework for you. And you don't want to cheat, do you?